GPS considerations for Robot: SPARTN, L5, anti-spoofing/anti-jamming
I am looking at adding a GPS module to my NVIDIA Jetson Orin NX. I am currently working on a robot that uses things depth cameras, lidar, etc, and I am looking to add a GPS module to fuse the GPS data with the camera image frames and the point cloud from the lidar. I plan on starting out to use the data to have it be able to communicate with other robots of where it is, using it for the robot to know where it is so it can use APIs to query and know how to navigate to waypoints, etc.
I am very new to programming and robotics, so I need some help with picking the right GPS module. I have a wifi module that I use to connect to a mobile hotspot that I carry with me so the robot has access to the internet (I use a hotspot over a embedded cellular module because it also acts as a router and I want to use this for some future plans I have). I was looking at first at:
“DigiKey Part Number 1568-GPS-22560-ND
Detailed Description NEO-D9S, ZED-F9P GNSS Receiver Evaluation Board”
please correct me if I am wrong, but to my understanding, I could use this with SPARTN, which has the ability to do real time corrections with GPS data from specific satellites as well as (I guess if the satellite data for the corrections is unavailable) use 3rd party RTK correction data from the internet. I thought this was a great solution because sometimes when cellular data is not working we can get those corrections from the satellites and when the satellite data is not efficient we can get the data from the internet with our cellular data.
the SPARTN compatibility comes from the NEO-D9S though in this product, correct?
another product I was looking at is come GPS modules from septentrio, which seems to be a very notable brand. I was looking at the mosaic H and its evolution board:
“DigiKey Part Number
2771-410359B1985HP3161-ND”
however, the evaluation board does not seem to support SPARTN, but I assume I can add SPARTN compatibility by adding something like the NEO-D9S, correct? But I see that the septentrio module also provides support for L5 frequency bands that have higher penetration and also means it will support future GPS protocols/architectures. I also see it has anti spoofing and anti jamming features. how resilient are these to spoofing and jamming?
if there are solutions that have L5 compatibility with SPARTN support and anti spoofing/jamming all in one, please let me know those products as I would like to have that all in one solution with a small form factor. something I like about the NEO-D9S, ZED-F9P GNSS Receiver Evaluation Board is it is small and I can add it very easily into my current configuration for my robot.
to summarize my questions:
1.) is the NEO-D9S, ZED-F9P GNSS Receiver Evaluation Board is SPARTN compatible?
2.) the NEO-D9S, ZED-F9P GNSS Receiver Evaluation Board SPARTN compatibilities comes from the NEO-D9S, right?
3.) with the SPARTN framework, I can get correction data through satellite signals without using the internet, correct?
4.) SPARTN also allows for using the internet to get the RTK correction data when the satellites cannot gather the correction data, correct?
5.) is having L5 frequency compatibility that much more useful? what are some other things I should know about what I can do with L5 and things you think I should know about it (maybe L5 frequency band is the only band that all future frameworks will be built off of, this would be important for me to know)
6.) would I have to manually add SPARTN compatibility for the septentrio evolution boards? if so, what are some ways I can do this.
7.) are the anti spoofing and jamming capabilities that useful? give me some examples or personal experience of when this has been useful in peoples applications
one last thing, is although I have a specific use for it now, I am alway adding more and more advanced functionalities to my projects. anytime I can make something better I do, to learn and also improve my projects overall. so I would like something with higher end functionalities, like L5 compatibility, anti spoofing/jamming, and if there are more functionalities other there tell me. but I do need it to be in a relatively small form factor, and would like for it to be an all in 1 kit. the form factor at the very very max is 100mm x 100mm x 30mm.
thank you in advance!
